# Snowflake slow JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a simple piece of code that tries to connect to Snowflake and run a simple query.
The strange thing is that establishing a connection takes over 3s, which is IMO super slow.
Do you have any idea why it happens?

My code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
    Instant startTime = Instant.now();
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, USER, PASSWORD)) {
      System.out.println("Connection time: " + Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()).toMillis() + "ms");
      PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name,age from user where id = ?");
      pstmt.setString(1, "0066488521");
      startTime = Instant.now();
      ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        String name = resultSet.getString("NAME");
        String age = resultSet.getString("AGE");
        System.out.println(name + ", " + age);
      }
      System.out.println("Query time: " + Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()).toMillis() + "ms");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Starting a new database connection is typically slow; The industry standard solution for this is to use a ConnectionPool.

Comment: Adding to it, is the connection to a PL enabled Snowflake account?

Comment: Can you enable [DEBUG](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC) and check the log file generated? 3s seems a bit too slow to me. Also have you checked in the Query History in Snowflake UI how much of the 3s was related to SQL itself (I assume it's just a few ms but worth checking as well)?